# git eclipse integration

Tags: git

I have installed EGit plugin in my eclipse(3.7). I have created a tunnel using putty, to a server where my git repository is present. Now, I tried changing the Git Configuration under Windows->Preferences->Git->Configurations. Added the following http settings under system properties:
http
proxyHost : localhost
proxyPort : 3128 (port on which my ssh tunner is established)
postBuffer : 524288000

While saving these configurations, i'm getting the following errors:

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.LockFile.lock(LockFile.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileBasedConfig.save(FileBasedConfig.java:175)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.preferences.ConfigurationEditorComponent.save(ConfigurationEditorComponent.java:151)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.preferences.GlobalConfigurationPreferencePage.performOk(GlobalConfigurationPreferencePage.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$13.run(PreferenceDialog.java:964)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.okPressed(PreferenceDialog.java:944)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.okPressed(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:447)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.okPressed(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.buttonPressed(PreferenceDialog.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ShowPreferencePageHandler.execute(ShowPreferencePageHandler.java:54)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Do I need to change some permission settings? Can some one explain what this error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running eclipse as administrator.

Right click on eclipse **Run as administrator**.

Comment: @user848066 Glad i help, If the answer was helpful please consider voting and or ticking as answer.